# Hosting provider's cPanel expired and we can't upload or download files

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel, ftp

My client's hosting provider's cPanel licence has either expired or number of users have exceeded limit. Now although my client has valid login credentials, he is unable to actually access the panel or files. The provider has probably disabled the ftp too, as the connection is not establishing.

The Hosting provider is not replying to any emails, calls, etc. presumably due to current Covid-19 situation.

Now all my client wants is to update or upload certain files just to keep on going or download the latest backup so that if this lack of response continues he can change his hosting provider.

1. If the cPanel licence has expired, whether there is a way to login and access the files with valid credentials. If there is a fall back panel, etc?
2. Is there a way to access or upload files via other means, if ftp is not connecting.
3. Is there a way to download the backup files since they are probably not in public_html folder.

Comment: What kind of site is it?  Static HTML?  WordPress?  Something else?

Comment: @Steve it's a dynamic website built in php. But the issue was temporary due to COVID-19. Services have resumed now.

Comment: Then you should answer your own question or delete it.

Answer (score -1):

Well If he has the WHM credentials, he can use them to connect via SFTP using Filezilla or some other similar client then download the files manually from the serv

Comment: Would a user of shared hosting have a WHM login?